# String variable returns an empty value

Tags: powerbuilder

Below is a PB function script that basically creates a reference number. This script is working in the production environment but there are cases that the string variable(ls_ivno) returns an empty value and I suspect that there is a deadlock which happens during this process.

Seeking help to trace if where is the possible problem on the this script.

```
String ls_branch, ls_gcode1, ls_ivprint, ls_ivno, ls_keyname
long ll_kcount

Select remarks11, remarks12, remarks13
Into :ls_branch, :ls_gcode1, :ls_ivprint
From ordersext
Where orderkey = :arg_orderkey;

ls_branch = trim(ls_branch)
ls_gcode1 = trim(ls_gcode1)
ls_ivprint = trim(ls_ivprint)

choose case ls_ivprint
    case 'SIV' //format1
        ls_ivno =  ls_branch + right(string(today(),"YY"),1) + "U" + ls_gcode1
    case 'IIV' //format2
        ls_ivno =  ls_branch + "Q" + string(today(),"YY") 
   case else  //blank
        ls_ivno = ' '
end choose

if ls_ivno <> ' ' then
        if ls_ivprint = 'SIV' THEN
            declare ncounter_invprn cursor for
            select keyname, keycount
            from ncounter
            where filler01 = 'invprn'
            order by keyname;

            open ncounter_invprn;
                fetch ncounter_invprn into :ls_keyname, :ll_kcount;
                do while sqlca.sqlcode = 0
                    setpointer(hourglass!)  
                    if ll_kcount <> 9999 then
                        ls_ivno += right(trim(ls_keyname),1) + f_get_ncounter(ls_keyname, 4)
                        close ncounter_invprn;
                    end if  
                fetch ncounter_invprn into :ls_keyname, :ll_kcount;
                loop
            close ncounter_invprn ;

        ELSE //IIV
            declare ncounter_invprn_iiv cursor for
            select keyname, keycount
            from ncounter
            where filler01 = 'invprn_iiv'
            order by keyname;

            open ncounter_invprn_iiv;
                fetch ncounter_invprn_iiv into :ls_keyname, :ll_kcount;
                do while sqlca.sqlcode = 0
                    setpointer(hourglass!)  
                    if ll_kcount <> 9999 then
                        ls_ivno += right(trim(ls_keyname),1) + f_get_ncounter(ls_keyname, 4)
                        close ncounter_invprn_iiv;
                    end if  
                fetch ncounter_invprn_iiv into :ls_keyname, :ll_kcount;
                loop
            close ncounter_invprn_iiv;

        END IF
end if      

return ls_ivno
```

Comment: is the variable actually empty, or null? it is not the same...

Comment: the variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

He return string is really empty or is it the string with a single space you put in ls_ivno  during the else of you "choose your box ls_ivprint".

What is the value of remarks13 in database for the lines for which you have an empty return?

You can put a "with ur" at the end of your queries. This prevent you from table lock. 
But the problem seems to be not here, you can not go beyond the query if the table is locked. Your Application is just freeze in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to check if the value is not null instead of empty with `isnull(ls_ivno)`.

An empty value would suggest that you are getting a null value from what you select in the database.

Beware that the null will always override an assignment or a concatenation if any of the terms is null. As a `if` test will always fail if any of the arguments is null and not properly handled with `isnull()`. In some way, the `null` value is contagious.

Comment: I had a major modification on the script earlier today and isnull() has been included as part of validation.

Comment: By the way, i know that using a cursor in PB scripting is working, but I would like to know if it's a best practice to used a cursor in PB?

Comment: A cursor is correct, but I find often more convenient to use a datastore that is easy to iterate and need less code changes when you need to modify the list of selected values (no need to declare storage variables and change the fetch statements). I have an improved inherited datastore with a `CreateFromSql()` method to ease the creation from a simple sql select.